# Refreshing current component on orientation change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've two components A and B displayed at the same time in left (A) and right (B) when device is in landscape. If portrait either the A or B will display as per the user selection. We can always go from A <-(push/pop)-> B. Both the components are having a common component (name as Footer (or in short F)) rendered (assume a tab bar).

Problem occurs when I change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape and vice versa. Specifically from Landscape to Portrait the B the common component F is not initialise until I do some interaction inside the B (like click to show a popup or scroll) and thus F will not have the effect which it should have until it initialise again.

Is there a way to invoke/initialise/refresh it?

I want a generic solution which I can apply in the common component F and don't want to make any change in A and B.

The object of `ChangeDetectorRef` which I am calling on orientation changes isn't fully helpful.

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
this.ref.markForCheck();
```

To add more information, it works 45 out of 50 times .. that 5 times it will not work (will not initialise). So still unsure where exactly the problem is.

Comment: A bit hard to visualize... could you provide a simple example on Stackblitz?

Comment: how are you listening to change orientation event? Please post code or otherwise create a stack blitz as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CGundlach and E. Maggini .. I found that the common component footer (F) it self was not getting added to the DOM due to a condition fail case. Able to fix the issue by correcting the condition.

Answer (score 0):

1-) `import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';`

2-) Add constructor:

```
 export class ClassName {
    ...
    constructor(...public screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation)
```

3-) Detect Orientation changes:

```
   this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe((data) => {

  if(this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT || 
    this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY || 
    this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_SECONDARY
    ){
      // Portrait. Your portrait code 
    }

  else if(this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE ||
          this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY || 
          this.screenOrientation.type == this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_SECONDARY
        ){
         // Landscape. Your landscape code
        }

    });
```